# Is IE9 compatibility mode a valid way to test IE7-8?

Tags: internet-explorer, testing, cross-browser

Working on a site that requires IE8 support. I'm testing the site on IE8 based in VMWare fusion - whereas my colleague is testing natively in windows on IE9 with compatibility mode on. We're seeing very different versions of the site, with my VMWare IE8 being closest to what the client is seeing on their IE8.

Is IE9 in compatibility mode a valid test for IE8? If not, what is it's purpose?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Compatibility View is designed to emulate the rendering engine used by IE7 rather than that of IE8. This is true for all versions with the feature, including 8, 9 and 10. That may be why your colleague is seeing different results from you and your client.

The right way to test for IE8 compatibility on IE9 is to use the F12 developer tools, which allow you to choose a rendering mode from either IE5.5 (quirks), IE7 (compatibility), IE8, and any of the later major versions up to whichever is in use.

The purpose of Compatibility View is to provide compatibility with much older sites that rely on legacy code which in turn relies on incorrect/inconsistent behavior in IE7 and older, which isn't as egregious or widespread in IE8 and later.

Comment: Thanks or the clear answer. I was looking everywhere to see how IE10's compatibility mode will render, and if it would be any different from IE9, or 8. Ah, so always back to IE7 in that mode huh?...

Answer (score 4):

To test in various older editions of IE...here's what you do...

1. In IE9 (or IE10), press F12
2. The developer tools will open up. Change the "Browser Mode" and "Document Mode" to anything you want (i.e. IE7,IE8 or even the notorious Quirks mode).

here's a screenshot:
[image]